# Preview Image when clicked- Android

Tags: java, android, gallery

I'm a novice Android developer. I used the code given at Google's Android developer site and developed the [gallery widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html).

Now I wanna tweak it. When the image is clicked currently it shows the index instead I wanna show the preview in the space available below the gallery.

As per my understanding I need to change the code somewhere here:

```
g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
            View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(HelloGallery.this, "" + position,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Instead of a Toast I wanna use some function that would bring up the preview. Can someone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkout [this](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views) and look into Gallery and ImageView Views example